# Next, Previous Records within a Group (Has Many)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hope anyone can assist. I have the next and previous buttons working to the next record within the database. however each project belongs to a Type, would like the buttons to be able to jump to the next record within the same Type.

Models

```
Project.rb
has_many :typelinks, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :types, :through => :typelinks

def self.get_previous_project(current_project)        
  Project.where("projects.id < ? ", current_project.id).order('id asc').last
end

def self.get_next_project(current_project)
  Project.where("projects.id > ? ", current_project.id).order('id asc').first
end

Type.rb
has_many :typelinks, :dependent =>:destroy
has_many :projects, :through =>:typelinks

typelink.rb
belongs_to :project
belongs_to :type
```

Above is the Relationship setup between projects and types. Below is the View Page on a Project. Hiding the Arrow if Last or First Record. (CSS Removed as i just need the Function to at the moment)

```
<% unless  @project.id == Project.first.id   %>
  <span id="leftarrow" class="prev"><%= link_to image_tag('/assets/prev_notext.png') + "", Project.get_previous_project(@project) %></span>
<% end %>

<% unless  @project.id == Project.last.id   %> 
  <span id="rightarrow" class="next"><%= link_to image_tag('/assets/next_notext.png') + "", Project.get_next_project(@project) %></span>
<% end %>
```

In Summary

This is an example of the function required.

Project1
Project2
Project3
Project4

Type1
Type2

Project2 and Project4 Belong to Type2.

When on the View Page of Project2 and click on the next arrow it needs to go to Project4 View and Not Project3.

I hope someone can assist me with this, sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
Project.joins(:types).where("projects.id < ? and types.id in (?)", current_project.id, current_project.types.map(&:id)).order('id asc').last
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, however it is just going to the next record in the database and not next in the Type.

Comment: Wait it does Work, was click on the next not Previous let me do some more tests

Comment: Thanks it works, only thing is when it gets to the last record in that Type, it moves to the Last record and Same on the first project